# Google.com serving *.portal.azure.com SSL certificate?

Tags: tls, google, azure

Just ran across this in my own browser (Chrome, Mac OS) where going to google.com would serve a *.portal.azure.com certificate. It seemed to be signed all the way to the root too.

This disappeared after 60-100 seconds.

[image]

What is the most likely cause for something like this?

Comment: Can be you are in MS' corpnet? You might have bluecoat style SSL proxy, with MS IT root cert installed on your machine? Note that certificate is signed by Microsoft IT, which is only used for their internal corpnet, and not the actual public Azure production cert.

Comment: No, not inside MS corpnet. Got a similar error with Akamai certs being issued for Google.com. Seemed like DNS was (is?) screwed up. It's gone now before I could capture the network IP trace.

Comment: Guessing interception at some level. Probably proxy. Also: Is DNS trustworthy? Run `nslookup google.com` next time that happens and check if that IP is really google.

Comment: FYI, securevizion.com is the business ISP here in San Diego ... haven't seen the integrity of DNS fail all day so far...